# How to fix invalid characters which shown in MessageBox in C++ DLL when calling it from Delphi app?

Tags: c++, delphi, dll, calling-convention

I have used Code::Blocks IDE for DLL and Delphi 10.3 Rio for Delphi app.

Here are my C++ DLL codes (CPP File):

```
#include "main.h"
#include "string"
#include "wchar2string.h"
using namespace std;
// a sample exported function
void DLL_EXPORT SomeFunction(wchar_t* sometext)
{
    string str = wchar2string(sometext);
    const char* cch = str.c_str();
    MessageBox(0, cch, "DLL Message", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}

extern "C" DLL_EXPORT BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD     fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            // attach to process
            // return FALSE to fail DLL load
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            // detach from process
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            // attach to thread
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            // detach from thread
            break;
    }
    return TRUE; // succesful
}
```

Here is my .H File:

```
#ifndef __MAIN_H__
#define __MAIN_H__

#include <windows.h>

/*  To use this exported function of dll, include this header
 *  in your project.
 */

#ifdef BUILD_DLL
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

void DLL_EXPORT SomeFunction(wchar_t* sometext);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // __MAIN_H__
```

And here are my Delphi codes:

```
const
  DLL = 'deneme dll.dll';

procedure MyProcedure(sometext: PWideChar); external DLL name 'SomeFunction';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyString: String;
begin
  MyString := Edit1.Text;
  MyProcedure(PWideChar(MyString));
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetErrorMode(0);
end;

end.
```

According to this website **PWideChar** is Delphi equivalent of **wchar_t*** in C++: **http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html**

So, when I clicked to Button1; I got this message:
[image]

And if DLL is not found, Delphi app throws this ('Application Stopped Working' Message):
[image]

So, **SetErrorMode(0);** is not working.

What I mean, I don't know anything about DLL programming and there is not any guideline about that in any website.

So, what should I do in order to make this working correctly?

Comment: Build your DLL as Unicode, not ANSI.  If you did that, there would be no reason for `wchar2string`.

Comment: " I am newbie at programming." - then you shouldn't be messing about with Delphi, C++, Code::Blocks, Windows programming and DLLs all at the same time.

Comment: *I have done so much research about this issue* -- Use `MessageBoxW` directly using `sometext` and drop using `wchar2string` or any funny conversion stuff we don't know about.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie MessageBox accepts const char*, so I converted wchar_t* to string (wchar2string), and I converted string to const char*.

Comment: @ÇAĞATAYKAYA -- Then do the obvious -- *stop using MessageBox*.  Now wasn't that easy?  Wasn't [MessageBoxW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messageboxw) part of your research?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ok, I changed MessageBox to MessageBoxW like you said; but IDE throws error like this: "cannot convert 'const char*' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}'"

Comment: @ÇAĞATAYKAYA All of your string parameters to `MessageBoxW` must be wide strings.  This `"DLL Message"` is not a wide string.  Wide strings are `L"DLL Message"`.  Again, it looks like you're doing too much, when you're missing the basics of the language and string handling.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ok, I did that too; then IDE compiled it. But this time I got this: https://imgur.com/a/nP0HbjF

Comment: Assuming you're using `sometext` with **no** conversion,  you are no longer getting the "Application stopped working error", which is what this post was about.  This is now about getting strings from a certain language to show up correctly, and that is another topic altogether.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know you are angry, I am sorry for that. But, I still get "Application stopped working error" if DLL is not found. I think Delphi app should only throw "DLL not found" error, not this one.

Comment: There is no anger.  What the issue really is that you're trying to do too much.  If you are writing a DLL function that expects wide strings, internally you should use wide-string functions, not try and do conversions from wide to narrow strings for no reason.  That's where `MessageBoxW` comes into play.  Now you have that taken care of, the issue no longer is what your original problem was, i.e. it has nothing to do with `MessageBox`.

Comment: It's the callibg convention. We can't tell what the C++ function's calling convention is, but it's not delphi register.

Comment: When a load time linked dll cannot be found, the OS terminates the process ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/load-time-dynamic-linking)). SetErrorMode requires a running process. I mean, the process terminates before you call it.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz you can solve that problem by including `delayed` in the Delphi declaration of the DLL function. Then the program will not terminate if the DLL is missing. Calling the DLL function will cause a runtime error instead.

Comment: @Remy That's only a solution if the code is wrong in the first place. Commonly it is desirable for a program to fail at load time when there are unresolved dependencies.

Comment: @Remy - Similarly you can use LoadLibrary-GetProcAddress yourself. Either way, it won't be a load time linked dll.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz yes, I'm aware of that (and that is what `delayed` uses internally). Sometimes that is desirable, to allow the app to fallback to an alternative instead of failing to run at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the C++ side, the conversion of `wchar_t*` to `std::string` is unnecessary. Just use the Unicode version of `MessageBox()` instead, eg:

```
void DLL_EXPORT SomeFunction(wchar_t* sometext)
{
    MessageBoxW(0, sometext, L"DLL Message", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
```

However, the main reason for your trouble is a calling convention mismatch.  On the Delphi side, the default calling convention is `register`, which is *very* different than the default of `__cdecl` used in C and C++. The Delphi declaration of the DLL function needs to specify the correct calling convention, eg:

```
procedure MyProcedure(sometext: PWideChar); cdecl; external DLL name 'SomeFunction';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyString: UnicodeString;
begin
  MyString := Edit1.Text;
  MyProcedure(PWideChar(MyString));
end;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, my DLL works like a charm. But, let's assume DLL is not found. In that case, Delphi app shows "Application has stopped working." error. I don't want to that error. Can I fix it without changing "Windows Error Reporting" settings? I mean, I want to catch that error.

Comment: @ÇAĞATAYKAYA you can solve that problem by including [`delayed`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Libraries_and_Packages_(Delphi)#Delayed_Loading_.28Windows-only.29) in the Delphi declaration of the DLL function. Then the program will not terminate if the DLL is missing. Calling the DLL function will cause a runtime error instead, which you can catch in a `try..except` block or a [failure notification hook](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/SysInit.SetDliFailureHook2).

Comment: Using 'delayed' statement inhibits 'stopped working' message; but also inhibits 'dll not found' message. As I mentioned it, I want to only inhibit 'stopped working' message. So, without 'delayed' statement is much better for me. Thanks any way.

Comment: @ÇAĞATAYKAYA "DLL not found" and "application stopped working" are two completely different and unrelated errors. If the DLL is missing and you don't use `delayed` then the app will fail to even load and will not execute any code at all, so you can't get a "not working" error. That only happens if the app terminates unexpectedly from a uncaught runtime crash, or has a deadlocked UI. Two different situations.